# OPENCV Merge several stitched images

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, plc, template-matching

I'd like to know if someone could give me any hint on the way to do this and if its a good idea.

Currently i'm working on a PLC that take pictures, but they are pasted one by one digitally.

I would like to use OpenCV to create a collage of images by removing similar parts from photos.

Exemple of 2 pictures of 25 making the whole image:

[image: Picture 0]

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Exemple in picture]

As the camera taking images is moving i guess there should be something like a percentage of accuracy.

Thank you anyone that could help me.

I'm currently on a solution using OPENCV trying to do it.

Comment: Maybe try https://github.com/OpenStitching/stitching